# The Invantive Control for Excel add-in makes Microsoft Excel start up slower

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control

When starting Microsoft Excel, it takes a bit longer to load due to the Invantive Control add-in. Is there any way I could disable the add-in when I won't be needing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always disable and enable the Invantive Control for Excel add-in as following:

Step 1: Go to 'File' and then 'Options'

[image: Go to File > Options]

Step 2: Click on "Add-Ins" in the menu on the left

[image: Click on "Add-Ins"]

Step 3: Choose "COM Add-ins" from the dropdown at the bottom next to "Manage:"

[image: Choose "COM Add-ins" from the dropdown]

Step 4: Disable the 'Invantive Control for Excel' add-in by clicking the checkbox

[image: Disable the add-in]

Now press OK, Invantive Control will be disabled.